# Why are the OpenGL functions using a mix of GLuint and GLint for attribute locations/indices?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to write a very simple OpenGL program, and I'm getting a bit confused by the mix of using GLint/GLuint.

[glGetAttribLocation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) returns the attribute location (index?) as a GLint, while

[glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) accepts a GLuint as the attribute index. Why aren't both using the same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the etymology of these functions.

`glVertexAttribPointer` was not created for GLSL specifically. It originally came from [ARB_vertex_program](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_program.txt), which is the old assembly shading language extension. `glVertexAttribPointer` used unsigned attribute indices. Also, it never had an API to query attribute indices; after all, it was for assembly where you hard-coded your attribute indices directly into your shader. Why would you need to query something you provided?

So, along comes GLSL, first defined by the [ARB_shader_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_objects.txt) extension (and written by the people at 3D Labs, a thankfully defunct organization, considering all of the *mistakes* they made with GLSL). They used signed integers for their locations. Note that the `glUniform*ARB` functions all take `GLint` rather than `GLuint`. So GLSL consistently uses signed integers for this sort of thing.

However, ARB_vertex_program already had functions for specifying attribute arrays to vertex shaders. Rather than create an entire new series of functions that do the same thing, their [ARB_vertex_**shader**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_shader.txt) extension just used the ones we already had. This allowed existing code to be able to use GLSL relatively painlessly.

But it created this inconsistency, because the GLSL extensions all use `GLint`, while `glVertexAttribPointer` used `GLuint`.